# Backbone Views not rendering when used with a Flask REST backend

Tags: javascript, python, rest, backbone.js, flask

I am using backbone and moustache to render a series of posts onto a page. The information is sent across the server through a REST Api as a JSON file (only GET at the moment). My problem is that I got all the code working on the frontend only first using a static json file and the data was rendered without a problem. However when I implemented this with flask and sqlite on the backend none of the content renders despite the fact that when I check in the console, all the data has been transferred across the server correctly and stored in the correct models. The only difference is that when I got it working in the beginning I was using a static json file with the exact same data. I am wondering if there is some sort of security issue preventing this from working?This is the first time I have tried to connect the server to the client so I apologise if I am have missed something very obvious though I have been stuck trying to figure this out all day. I will post the Python and JavaScript below In case anybody knows what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Python/Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/posts')
def create_json():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("posts.sqlite")
    curs = connection.cursor()

    curs.execute('SELECT * FROM posts_table')
    posts = [dict(Name=row[0], Text=row[1], Date=row[2], Email=row[3]) for row in curs.fetchall()]
    connection.close()

    return json.dumps(posts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

JavaScript/Backbone:

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: "/posts"

});

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Post,

    url: "/posts"

});

var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    class: "row",

    render: function(){
        var template = $("#postTemplate").html();
        var html = Mustache.render(template, this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);

        return this;
    }

});

var PostsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#container1",

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var self = this;

        this.model.each(function(post){
            var postView = new PostView({model: post});
            self.$el.append(postView.render().$el);
        });
    }

});

var posts = new Posts();

posts.fetch({
    success: function(){
        successCallback();
        reset: true
    }
});

var successCallback = function(){
    posts.orderByDate()
    var postsView = new PostsView({model: posts})
};
```

Comment: Instead of json.dumps, try using flask.jsonify. It sets the headers for a json response

Comment: Also, is the Flask server on the same domain as your Backbone files? You might be running in to CORS problems trying to fetch your data from a different domain/port

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. They are on the same domain and the fetch has worked successfully as all the correct attributes are in the models so I don't think its a CORS issue. I could try use jsonify instead though I don't know if it will help because the headers are the correct ones already.